# Two HG659 modem, setup

Tags: modem, wireless-bridge, fiber

I have two identical Huawei HG659 home gateway
 One is working properly on fiber connection, as the house is big I would like to know if the second modem (that is not in use) can be used as repetitor of the first one to extend the wireless network to the rooms with no internet. 
I need the information on how to set up as an extension as well.
Any help is more than welcome.

Comment: Ho DavidPostill, the HG659 is a router connected to the home gateway Fiber

Comment: Ah. It has a integrated Ethernet WAN port so it might be possible.

Comment: Any chance to help me with this second modem setup?

Comment: Sorry, never done that.

Answer (score 0):

disable the DHCP option and set your second modem interface ip address to different ip address which can not be the same as your main modem